How to connect to MongoDB using PySpark?
I want to connect to a MongoDb database using PySaprk. I have downloaded mongo-spark-connector_2.12-10.1.0-all.jar and copied it to the Spark jars directory.
This is my code.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

working_directory = "C://spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3//jars//*"

uri = "mongodb://my_user:my_password@my_host:27017/my_db?authSource=admin"

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri) \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", uri) \
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', working_directory) \
    .getOrCreate()

def read_from_mongo(collection_name):
    return spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
                     .option("collection", collection_name) \
                     .load()

df_collection1 = read_from_mongo("my_collection")
df_collection1.printSchema()

I get this error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o175.load. :
org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND]
Failed to find the data source: com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource.
Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html.

I don't know how to fix this. I've tried several solutions and I always get the same error.
My Spark version is 3.5.0 and I'm running it local

This error shows that there is no "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource" format that can be used when you use Spark to read the data.
I checked the MongoDB docs (v10.1). It should work with using .format("mongodb") if both your JAR and Spark version are compatible.
